# How to delete from mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want to delete some entries in a MySQL database when I go to this URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/td

I have a file named database.py and it has:

```
engine = create_engine(config.database_uri)
def delete():
    with engine.connect() as con:
        con.execute("delete from INS where a = 2;")
```

I have a file named **init**.py and it has:

```
@app.route('/api/td', methods=["DELETE"])
def update():
    database.delete()
    return 'succefully'
```

when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/td, I get this error:
There was an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/td.

The method above worked perfectly for multiple get requests. But it's not working for my delete request. both files have other codes and imports.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

When a route is visited via browser, it performs a `GET` request.

So, visiting `/api/td` that is declared with only `DELETE` method will result in `Method not allowed` error.

[image: Method not allowed error while accessing a route with DELETE method]

**Solution:**

To overcome this, we need to declare the route with `GET` method instead of `DELETE`:

```
@app.route("/api/td", methods=['GET'])
```

I have created a dummy application to delete a row from MySQL database table.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from database import Database

app = Flask(__name__)
database = Database()

@app.route("/api/td", methods=['GET'])
def delete_row():
    return database.delete()

app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

`database.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class Database(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
        self.engine = create_engine('mysql://root:123@localhost/practice_db')

    def delete(self):
        try:
            with self.engine.connect() as con:
                con.execute('DELETE FROM `user_table` WHERE `id`=2')
                return 'Deleted successfully'
        except Exception as e:
            return "Exception occurs: {}".format(str(e))
```

*requirements.txt*:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
mysqlclient==1.3.13
SQLAlchemy==1.2.14
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Screenshot:

[image: deleted database row]